# How is this element accessible when not found with selector

Tags: javascript, html

In my company, some of the code accesses html elements purely by id, rather than `document.getElementById` or jQuery `$("#id")`.  For example, if there is a select with an id of test they then use `alert(test.selectedIndex)` in the javascript and this works.

This breaks my model of how elements can be found / accessed in the DOM and I would have expected the alert to say that test was undefined.  However, this works (and I have set up a fiddle to double check this).  Can anyone please explain why elements can be accessed by their id, without any need for a `getElementById` / jQuery selector?

Many thanks.

Comment: Browsers add elements with an `id` as a property of the global object, so `window.id === document.getElemementById('id')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object (noting that 'globals' in javascript are just looked up from properties on the window object, so `window[id]` is exactly the same as just `id`, if id is not defined as a local variable)

This was previously non-standard behaviour, added by IE, that has now become part of the HTML5 spec.

In general I wouldn't recommend relying on it though because, as you've noticed, it can be quite confusing.